# iMessage sticker not working outside of simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, imessage, imessage-extension

I created quickly a sticker pack for iMessage with XCODE preset but it's not working when I send it to my iPhone XS Max. When I use the simulator on an iPhone 11, it's working fine, but on my iPhone the sticker pack crash on first launch, and then icon is not showing and it shows empty. 
I don't have any notion of Swift language, so I'm not able to understand the errors.
I‘m just trying to make this sticker as an extra stuff for my bachelor semester evaluation. If someone could help me on this one, I'd be so grateful.

Here is the console log of when I upload it to my iPhone:

```
   error: attach by pid '672' failed -- no such process.
2022-01-17 12:11:52.263254+0100 MobileSMS[670:28648] [ServerBag] Checked bag access permission -- allowed? YES {self: <IDSCourierServerBag: 0x281c155c0>, hasMachAccess: YES, hasEntitlements: YES}
2022-01-17 12:11:52.363775+0100 MobileSMS[670:28662] [PAAccessLogger] Failed to log access with error: access=<PATCCAccess 0x28275f690> accessor:<<PAApplication 0x280a131b0 identifierType:inProcess assumedIdentity:(null)>> identifier:A08A13E1-F142-46D2-B8A6-16D8A2DF9646 kind:intervalEnd timestampAdjustment:0 tccService:kTCCServiceAddressBook, error=Error Domain=PAErrorDomain Code=10 "Possibly incomplete access interval automatically ended by daemon"
2022-01-17 12:11:52.411754+0100 MobileSMS[670:28646] [Warning] Could not determine if com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin is a recent or favorite!
2022-01-17 12:11:52.535336+0100 MobileSMS[670:28646] [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will only be logged once.
2022-01-17 12:11:52.684382+0100 MobileSMS[670:28646] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-01-17 12:11:52.736162+0100 MobileSMS[670:28646] [Warning] Could not determine if com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin is a recent or favorite!
2022-01-17 12:11:52.741616+0100 MobileSMS[670:28646] [Warning] Could not determine if com.apple.messages.browser.MorePlugin is a recent or favorite!
2022-01-17 12:11:53.413671+0100 MobileSMS[670:28646] [TraitCollection] Class CKBrowserSwitcherViewController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
2022-01-17 12:11:53.436811+0100 MobileSMS[670:28646] [NSExtension] Extension request contains input items but the extension point does not specify a set of allowed payload classes. The extension point's NSExtensionContext subclass must implement `+_allowedItemPayloadClasses`. This must return the set of allowed NSExtensionItem payload classes. In future, this request will fail with an error. Extension: <EXConcreteExtension: 0x281c25800> {id = fr.alexisgargaloni.ECAL-Feel-good---Alexis-Gargaloni.StickerPackExtension} Items: (
    "<NSExtensionItem: 0x282b0c580> - userInfo: {\n    \"context-is-primary\" = 1;\n    \"host-view-bounds\" = \"NSRect: {{0, 0}, {0, 27}}\";\n}"
)
2022-01-17 12:11:53.480000+0100 MobileSMS[670:28653] [lifecycle] [u 0C8AD0DC-26EC-4455-A474-FC1E4988B671:m (null)] [fr.alexisgargaloni.ECAL-Feel-good---Alexis-Gargaloni.StickerPackExtension(1.0)] Failed to start plugin; pkd returned an error: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=4 "RBSLaunchRequest error trying to launch plugin fr.alexisgargaloni.ECAL-Feel-good---Alexis-Gargaloni.StickerPackExtension(0C8AD0DC-26EC-4455-A474-FC1E4988B671): Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launched process exited during launch." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launched process exited during launch.}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=RBSLaunchRequest error trying to launch plugin fr.alexisgargaloni.ECAL-Feel-good---Alexis-Gargaloni.StickerPackExtension(0C8AD0DC-26EC-4455-A474-FC1E4988B671): Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launched process exited during launch." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launched process exited during launch.}}
2022-01-17 12:11:53.480116+0100 MobileSMS[670:28653] [NSExtension] Plugin <id<PKPlugIn>: 0x10285b520; core = <[u 0C8AD0DC-26EC-4455-A474-FC1E4988B671] [fr.alexisgargaloni.ECAL-Feel-good---Alexis-Gargaloni.StickerPackExtension(1.0)],[d 88079B57-94D8-4D22-BFA5-F007F012FCAB] [/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B972BCCA-06C7-4B10-95FA-65BAB8F63DB8/ECAL Feel good – Alexis Gargaloni.app/PlugIns/ECAL Feel good – Alexis Gargaloni StickerPackExtension.appex]>, instance = [(null)], state = 3, useCount = 0> must have pid! Extension request will fail
2022-01-17 12:11:53.480173+0100 MobileSMS[670:28653] [NSExtension] Failed to aquire assertion for plugin: <id<PKPlugIn>: 0x10285b520; core = <[u 0C8AD0DC-26EC-4455-A474-FC1E4988B671] [fr.alexisgargaloni.ECAL-Feel-good---Alexis-Gargaloni.StickerPackExtension(1.0)],[d 88079B57-94D8-4D22-BFA5-F007F012FCAB] [/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B972BCCA-06C7-4B10-95FA-65BAB8F63DB8/ECAL Feel good – Alexis Gargaloni.app/PlugIns/ECAL Feel good – Alexis Gargaloni StickerPackExtension.appex]>, instance = [(null)], state = 3, useCount = 0> pid: 0
2022-01-17 12:11:53.480209+0100 MobileSMS[670:28653] [NSExtension] Unable to acquire process assertion in beginUsing: with plugin identifier: fr.alexisgargaloni.ECAL-Feel-good---Alexis-Gargaloni.StickerPackExtension, killing plugin
2022-01-17 12:11:53.480250+0100 MobileSMS[670:28651] [NSExtension] begin extension request <EXExtensionRequest: 0x283c06400> Request PK UUID: 752EBE94-8BAB-4B2C-AC96-896F00B8B81B with item count 1 complete with error: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=4 "RBSLaunchRequest error trying to launch plugin fr.alexisgargaloni.ECAL-Feel-good---Alexis-Gargaloni.StickerPackExtension(0C8AD0DC-26EC-4455-A474-FC1E4988B671): Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launched process exited during launch." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launched process exited during launch.}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=RBSLaunchRequest error trying to launch plugin fr.alexisgargaloni.ECAL-Feel-good---Alexis-Gargaloni.StickerPackExtension(0C8AD0DC-26EC-4455-A474-FC1E4988B671): Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launched process exited during launch." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launched process exited during launch.}}
2022-01-17 12:11:53.480546+0100 MobileSMS[670:28653] [NSExtension] PlugInKit error in beginUsing: with plugin identifier: fr.alexisgargaloni.ECAL-Feel-good---Alexis-Gargaloni.StickerPackExtension, killing plugin
```

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue. Were you able to figure anything out?

I'm seeing this intermittently in the simulator also. It almost feels like the sticker pack Xcode deployment is just broken/inconsistent.

Comment: I figured it my issue. I had to go to Settings > General > VPN & Device Management > DEVELOPER APP and trust the developer who has signed the app. Then it started working.

Comment: oh man, thanks so much! I had the exact same issue and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. "Extension request contains input items but the extension point does not specify a set of allowed payload classes." is such a non-descriptive error. I have no idea how you figured this out, but this also work for me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to highlight the answer by SpencerL in the comments above: Apparently this is a permission issue and the solution is to trust the developer in the iphone settings. Namely, go to Settings > General > VPN & Device Management > DEVELOPER APP and trust the developer who has signed the app.